# Bulletitems and Subbulletitems disappeared after adding lmodern to my document. Can you help me fix this issue?

Tags: fonts, packages, moderncv, lmodern

I had `\usepackage{fontawesome}` in my document, and bullet-/subbullet-items worked properly. I wanted to switch to lmodern, and added `\usepackage{lmodern}` to my document. The font has changed to lmodern and everything else remained unchanged, except all the bullets/subbullets disappeared from my document. I tried uploading the `lmodern` package to my document, but it did not accept the file.

Currently I have GNUFreefont and Tinos in my Font tab. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- add an short compilable tex code resulting in your issue. Then we can copy the code an test it on our own computer ...